# Question about infinite integral convergence logic

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

For a question, I was given the continuous function f, who's lim as x goes to infinity = 2, and I have to determine if it's possible for the infinite integral of f(x) to be convergent. Would someone be able to help me with this? Not really sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The improper integral will be divergent. Here's a proof of this fact:

Let's assume that $f$ is defined on $[a,\infty)$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=2$, then for any given $\varepsilon >0$, there will exist a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-2|<\varepsilon$ for all $x>\delta$. As a special case, there will exist a $\delta_1$ such that $|f(x)-2|<1$ for all $x>\delta_1$.

The inequality $|f(x)-2|<1$ is equivalent to $-1<f(x)-2<1$, which in turn is equivalent to $1<f(x)<3$. It follows from basic integral properties and the fact that $f$ and $1$ are continuous and strictly positive for all real $t>\delta$ that

$$\int_{\delta}^{t}1\text{ }dx<\int_{\delta}^{t}f(x)\text{ }dx$$

It is clear that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\delta}^{t}1\text{ }dx=\infty$, so the inequality $\int_{\delta}^{t}1\text{ }dx<\int_{\delta}^{t}f(x)\text{ }dx$ implies that it must be true that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\delta}^{t}f(x)\text{ }dx=\infty$ (this argument can be generalized to prove part of the Comparison Test for Integrals). This means that $\int_{\delta}^{\infty}f(x)\text{ }dx$ is divergent. Since adding a finite, ordinary integral won't change this, we conclude that the whole improper integral $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\text{ }dx$ will also be divergent.